# Problema con angularjs, en una vista

Tags: angularjs

Estimados tengo un modal con el siguiente codigo en el controlador:
$scope.ObtenerReclamosWebContrato = function() {

```
           //if($scope.id_contrato2){
            HttpsService.get('/atencion-usuario-web/contrato/142771/requerimiento-comercial')
            .then(function (response) {
                    data = response.data;
                    console.log(data);

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'template-modal-otr.html',
                    controller: 'ModalOtrCtrl',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    size: "lg",
                    
                    resolve: {items: function () {
                            return data;
                        }}
                    });
    
            }).catch(function () {
            });
           //}  //llave del if                
        }
```

Y el objeto que genera ahi es este:
"data": [
{
"id": 9,
"id_contrato": 142771,
"id_user": 2,
"codigo_motivo": "FND",
"observacion": "PRUEBA RECLAMOS COMERCIALESSDF dfdas",
"id_usuario_asignado": 106,
"id_caso": null,
"fecha_asignacion": "2020-08-10 02:06:41",
"created_at": "2020-08-09T20:25:35.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-08-10T02:06:41.000000Z"
}
]
muestra en el navegador, pero no me enlaza a mi modal, no muestra los datos, este es mi modal:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template-modal-otr.html">
    <div class="panel panel-genesys">
        <div class="header_popup text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" title="Cerrar">×</button>
            <h1 class="panel-title"> Atender Requerimiento Web </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body form-genesys">

            <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-genesys">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr_header">
                        <th class="tr-center">Codigo Motivo</th>
                        <th class="tr-center">Observacion</th>
                        <th class="options-1" disabled-auth type-authen="Edit"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
              {{ data | json }}
                <tbody class="table-size">
                    <tr ng-repeat="obj in data" ng-controller="dalOtrCtrl">
                        <td>{{obj.id | uppercase}}</td>
                        <td>{{obj.id_contrato | uppercase}}</td>


                        <td disabled-auth type-authen="Edit" class="has-option">
                            <a genesys-tooltip title="Editar" class="option" href="" ng-click="btn_edit(obj)" ><span class="icon-edit"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>






           
                
                 
                    <div class="row form-genesys">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group  text-center clearfix">
                                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-lg btn-genesys" type-authen="Add" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="formUsuario.$invalid">
                                    <span class="detail">Guardar</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

               

        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la respuesta, me faltaba el scope:

$scope.ObtenerReclamosWebContrato = function() {

```
           //if($scope.id_contrato2){
            HttpsService.get('/atencion-usuario-web/contrato/142771/requerimiento-comercial')
            .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.data = response.data;
                  //  console.log(data);

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    scope: $scope,
                    templateUrl: 'template-modal-otr.html',
                    controller: 'ModalOtrCtrl',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    size: "lg",
                    
                    resolve: {items: function () {
                            return $scope.data;
                        }}
                    });
    
            }).catch(function () {
            });
           //}  //llave del if                
        }
```